# How to replace tf.train.batch , as it is deprecated

Tags: python, tensorflow, petastorm

This is the code for training mnist data using Petastorm.

```py
def train_and_test(dataset_url, training_iterations, batch_size, evaluation_interval):

    with make_reader(os.path.join(dataset_url, 'train'), num_epochs=None) as train_reader:
        with make_reader(os.path.join(dataset_url, 'test'), num_epochs=None) as test_reader:
            train_readout = tf_tensors(train_reader)
            train_image = tf.cast(tf.reshape(train_readout.image, [784]), tf.float32)
            train_label = train_readout.digit
            batch_image, batch_label = tf.train.batch(
                [train_image, train_label], batch_size=batch_size
            )
```

I don't know how to replace `tf.train.batch`.  Could you please help with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dataset.batch` with `tf.data.Dataset` and `petastorm` also supports `tf.data.Dataset` which is mentioned in their website.

For code on implementing `tf.data.Dataset` with `petastorm` you can get it [here](https://petastorm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme_include.html#tensorflow-api).
For details on `dataset.batch` you can find it [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#batch).